# Install Traceroute on windows' MSYS2 using pacman

Tags: windows, archlinux, msys2, traceroute, pacman-package-manager

I try to install `traceroute` on MSYS2. Using its `pacman` package manager, I update the index:

```
pacman -Fy
```

and search for traceroute:

```
pacman -Fs traceroute
```

It finds nothing...

Could I use any pacman packages source to install things on MSYS2? For example, could I use the ArchLinux' [`tracroute`](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/core/i686/traceroute/)?

- If yes, how?
- If not, how to proceed to get `traceroute` running on MSYS2?

*Note: Has a lazy solution, I installed a bunch of useful packages with `pacman -S --needed base-devel msys2-devel`. It seems that traceroute is not an essential developper tool...*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Traceroute is a part (should be) of `inetutils` MSYS2 package. Currently the [`PKGBUILD`](https://github.com/Alexpux/MSYS2-packages/blob/master/inetutils/PKGBUILD) disabled it's compilation:

```
    ...
    --disable-uucpd --disable-ifconfig \
    --enable-dnsdomainname \
    --disable-traceroute \ # Here
    ac_cv_func_mmap_fixed_mapped=no
make
```

You can try cloning `MSYS2-packages` repo and rebuilding this package or just using windows `tracert.exe` tool.

Comment: yeah, I've seen traceroute was disabled in ````PKGBUILD````... Don't have time to rebuild it. I'll use tracert instead.

Comment: @jvtrudel You can also try using [nmap](https://nmap.org/download.html): `nmap -sP --traceroute`. It also supports different modes of operation (UDP/TCP/ICMP)

Comment: ````nmap```` is not available... It seems there: ````pacman -Fs nmap```` gives me : ````msys/bash-completion 2.3-1     usr/share/bash-completion/completions/nmap````. Pacman don't want to install it: ````pacman -S nmap```` gives me ````pacman can't find the target: nmap````. I think I don't understand pacman, I am more familiar with apt-get...

Comment: @jvtrudel Sorry, I forgot that it is not available in the repo (at least now). You could try using the official `.exe` installer (which also installs optional `Npcap` driver for some low-level packet spoofing)